# Uable to dial two special symbols together using ACTION_DIAL in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to open dial pad programmatically and write (*+) together but I am only getting only one character when I run the app
Below is my code:-

```
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("* + ")));
            notificationIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Try this `Uri.parse("tel:*" + Uri.encode("+"))`

Comment: just tried not worked